# What is the best solution to share files between diffrent host machines (file system)

Tags: architecture, filesystems, microservices, ceph, glusterfs

I need advice in storage architecture. I have 2 servers for video encoding and 1 machine to handle uploads and requests. Every machine has its own hard drive, and now I need an idea of how to connect all these hard drivers to create single storage. I have already try config glusterfs but I have to say it is pretty challenging. Should I use something else or stick to gluster?

Comment: have you tried nfs?

Answer (score 0):

What all things you tried with GlusterFS? What type of Storage is required, do you want to get double the storage space or redundant copy?

If storage to be added as single Volume then use Distributed Gluster Volume, if redundancy is required then use the Replicate Volume.

I am answering the question assuming that you are combining the storage to get the single Volume.

Install GlusterFS in both the nodes/machines. Let us say two machines are

```
node1.example.com
node2.example.com
```

Login to the machine 1 and invite the other machine to the Cluster.

```
root@node1 # gluster peer probe node2.example.com
```

After this, prepare the disk and mount it to use as storage units. For example if the device path is `/dev/sdc` then

```
root@node1 # mkfs.xfs -i size=512 /dev/sdc
root@node1 # mkdir -p /bricks/myvol/brick1
root@node1 # mount /dev/sdc /bricks/myvol/brick1
```

Repeat the same thing in other machine

```
root@node2 # mkfs.xfs -i size=512 /dev/sdc
root@node2 # mkdir -p /bricks/myvol/brick2
root@node2 # mount /dev/sdc /bricks/myvol/brick2
```

Now login to any one machine, create and start the Gluster Volume

```
root@node1 # gluster volume create myvol          \
     node1.example.com:/bricks/myvol/brick1/brick \
     node2.example.com:/bricks/myvol/brick2/brick
root@node1 # gluster volume start myvol
```

Now create the mount points in both the machines and mount the Gluster Volume.

```
root@node1 # mkdir -p /mnt/myvol
root@node1 # mount -t glusterfs localhost:/myvol /mnt/myvol
```

```
root@node2 # mkdir -p /mnt/myvol
root@node2 # mount -t glusterfs localhost:/myvol /mnt/myvol
```

Now your encoder application can use `/mnt/myvol` as persistent storage between two nodes.

Gluster Volume size in this example is sum of storage space provided in each node(`sum(brick sizes)`). For example if both nodes/machines has `10GiB` disk then the Gluster Volume size will be `20GiB`.

If you want redundancy that means when a machine is not available then also data should be available then change the Volume create command to

```
root@node1 # gluster volume create myvol replica 2 \
     node1.example.com:/bricks/myvol/brick1/brick  \
     node2.example.com:/bricks/myvol/brick2/brick
```

**Note**: Volume size will be `min(bricks_size)` since the same files are stored in both the machines.